# Group a query result to get this format

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following schema:

```
a VARCHAR(255),
b INTEGER,
c INTEGER,
d TEXT
```

In my database, if d is not null, then c is 0. What I would like to do is group all columns that have equal `a`s and equal `b`s. However, I'd like to use the sum of `c` for the result and the non-null value of `d` (if there is one). For instance, if my data looked like this:

```
"XXX" 100 1 NULL
"XXX" 100 1 "my text"
"YYY" 5 1 NULL
"YYY" 7 0 "other text"
```

I would like the result to be:

```
"XXX" 100 2 "my text"
"YYY" 5 1 NULL
"YYY" 7 0 "other text"
```

Is there a query I can use that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_concat to concatenate the values of column d into one field

```
SELECT a, b, SUM(c), GROUP_CONCAT(d)
FROM table
GROUP BY a, b
ORDER BY a asc, b asc
```

If you have two rows like

```
"XXX", 100, 0, "Some Text"
"XXX", 100, 0, "Some More Text"
```

This will return

```
"XXX", 100, 0, "Some Text,Some More Text"
```

However if you have three rows:

```
"XXX", 100, 0, "Some Text"
"XXX", 100, 0, "Some More Text"
"XXX", 100, 1, NULL
```

You will get

```
"XXX", 100, 1, "Some Text,Some More Text"
```

(ie, the null will disappear.  Use coalesce if you need to maintain a placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this just using `max()`:

```
select a, b, sum(c) as c, max(d) as d
from table t
group by a, b;
```